# soapClient use SoapFault or Exception or both to catch Error?

Tags: php, soap-client

Which of the following is better to catch an error when calling a web service using SoapClent?

```
try {
  $response = $client->SomeSoapRequest();
}
  catch(SoapFault $e){
}
```

Or:

```
try {
  $response = $client->SomeSoapRequest();
}
  catch(SoapFault $e){
}
  catch(Exception $e){
}
```

Also, I want to catch a socket timeout; will this be a `SoapFault` or an `Exception`?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Soap timeouts in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835184/handling-soap-timeouts-in-php)

Answer (score 7):

Just catch Exception; this will also catch SoapFault. If you need to know the difference, you can check the type of the object received. Exception will also catch other non-soapfault exceptions, which you should be doing anyway. So, the answer is: the second one.

Answer (score 2):

you can find some answers at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835184/handling-soap-timeouts-in-php).

Comment: I actually had read that question, but no answers found. Thanks!